# How to set Spring active profile programatically in my test class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a springBoot test class that I want to run with two different profiles which can be switched ideally through the build.gradle or using profiles.
I am using @ActiveProfiles annotation to specify which spring profile to use for testing. I want to switch between two different test profiles based on whether I want e2e testing or not, without having to make a code change every time. I tried using a resolver but it always sets to ITPRofile.
Here is the annotation:

```
`@ActiveProfiles(value = "ITProfile", resolver = SystemPropertyActiveProfileResolver.class)
`
```

Here is the resolver:

```
`public class SystemPropertyActiveProfileResolver implements ActiveProfilesResolver {

  private final DefaultActiveProfilesResolver defaultActiveProfilesResolver =
      new DefaultActiveProfilesResolver();

  @Override
  public String[] resolve(Class<?> testClass) {
    final String springProfileKey = "spring.profiles.active";
    return System.getProperties().containsKey(springProfileKey)
        ? System.getProperty(springProfileKey).split("\\s*,\\s*")
        : defaultActiveProfilesResolver.resolve(testClass);
  }
}`
```

When I evaluate System.getProperties() it doesn't have any key value pair for spring.profiles.active. How can I make the property available to the resolver? Without the activeProfiles annotation the profile in my test class is simply set to be the one in my application.yml

I tried setting spring.profiles.active in my build.gradle, but it doesn't look like it is picked by the springboot test class.
I tried printing `System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")` in the resolver but it was null.
I tried printing `System.getenv()` but there was no key corresponding to an active profile
How can I make the resolver set the correct profile? Where should I be defining it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused at your requirements.  You want to run both unit tests *and* E2E tests from the same class?  Is separating the classes that do E2E from unit tests not an option?

Comment: @Makoto thanks for taking a look at the question. I need to use the same class for integration and module testing. The same tests are reusable for both. Hence I just want to be able to change the profile with which my test is run.

Comment: Can you explain more on this "need"?  Normally the convention even in Spring testing is to split the two up.  Is there something else mandating that?

Comment: @Makoto The test code is the same for both profiles, the only thing that varies is some properties in the yml files for both. I know I can always have two separate test files but I am trying to avoid that and make the above approach work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you want to hear, but it's a lot easier to separate this into two separate test classes.

Here's why.

1. With JUnit Jupiter, you can [tag long-running tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-tagging-and-filtering).  This would allow you to have one file that is your E2E test suite, and one that is your unit tests.  On top of that...
2. It is ***way*** easier to control the properties for a whole test class rather than by profile.  The easiest way to do this is through `@SpringBootTest` which allows you to load in a profile-specific properties file (through [the usual means in Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.profile-specific)).  Then this begets...
3. It's ***way*** simpler to keep track of a failed test in a specific context than to have the context munged together.  This can't be overstated; knowing that your test failed because it was an E2E test is better than assuming or guessing.  Keeping your tests consistent and concise to understand what it is you are or aren't testing at any given time is vital to writing good tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't e2e vs unit tests. I have a separate suite for unit tests. I am doing IT vs component testing, which are both part of e2e testing the only difference being one calls downstream apis and other doesn't. So while I already have different profiles for e2e vs unit, in this particular scenario I am looking to have one test file work for both.